# Google cloud messaging on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2

Is there any way to receive GCM in Raspberry Pi, so I can use it to print on thermal printer that message?

Or can I install windows with GUI, then install chrome and watch messages?

Or any other solution to receive message from GCM?

Comment: It looks like there's a Python client library available for interacting with GCM: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gcm-client/ . Might be worth a look.

Comment: But this can only send message, i need to receive messages on raspberry.

Comment: As is often the case, the docs are helpful: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream#handle_upstream_message_callbacks_1